# How to use the result from a SQL query as keyword to do another SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I like to create a table which can show parts ID, parts name and its most recent supplier's name. These information are separated in 3 tables - BOM table(Field Name=>drawingN, partsID, partsName), purchase_history table (partsID, supplierID, purchaseDate) and supplier_list table(supplierID, supplierName).

In BOM table, parts are categorize by drawing number, so I use following SQL to get parts ID that I want:

```
SELECT drawingN, partsID, partsName
FROM BOM
WHERE drawingN = 'I16253'
```

In purchase_history, because the same parts may purchased from different supplier over time, so I use following SQL to screen out the most recent one. I also LEFT JOIN supplier_list to make supplier name shown in the table. In addition, supplierID 2991 and 2992 means oders that had been canceled or modified, so I what to rule them out too.

```
SELECT TOP 1 purchase_history.partsID, supplier_list.supplierName
FROM purchase_history
LEFT JOIN supplier_list ON purchase_history.supplierID = supplier_list.supplierID
WHERE partsID = 'A1234' AND supplierID <> '2991' AND supplierID <> '2992'
ORDER BY purchaseDate DESC
```

From first SQL query, database returns:

| drawingN | partsID | partsName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I16253 | A1234 | Bolts |
| I16253 | B5678 | Spring |

From second SQL query, database returns:

| partsID | supplierName |
| --- | --- |
| A1234 | ABC Company |

Is it possible to combine first and second SQL to make database returns something like this:

| drawingN | partsID | partsName | supplierName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I16253 | A1234 | Bolts | ABC Company |
| I16253 | B5678 | Spring | DEF Company |

Now I just keep chaning partsID = 'A1234' to partsID = 'B5678' in second SQL to get B5678's company name. I tried subquery, but it doesn't go right. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Something smells with that `LEFT JOIN`. You don't qualify `supplierid` in the `WHERE` do you'll get an ambiguous column error, but I'm wonder *why* there wouldn't be a value for the supplier in the `Supplier`. If the value of the `SupplierID` can be `NULL` then you're still implicitly filtering those values out as `<> NULL` resolves to UNKNOWN. Do you *actually* want an `INNER JOIN`? Things just don't add up here.

Comment: I could swear I have seen this question already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it should be:

```
DECLARE @drawing varchar(11) = 'I16253';

SELECT b.drawingN, b.partsID, b.partsName, sub.supplierName
FROM dbo.BOM AS b
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP (1) s.supplierName
  FROM dbo.purchase_history AS ph
  INNER JOIN dbo.supplier_list AS s
  ON ph.supplierID = s.supplierID
  WHERE ph.partsID = b.partsID
  AND s.supplierID NOT IN ('2991','2992')
  ORDER BY ph.purchaseDate DESC
) AS sub
WHERE b.drawingN = @drawing;
```

I tried to work out what made the most sense based on the *description*, not the existing code, using [this example on fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/awp87-qC).

Comment: Should `AND s.supplierID NOT IN ('2991','2992')` not be in the `ON`? Otherwise you have an implicit `INNER JOIN` here.

Comment: @ThomA yep... this is why I promised myself to stop answering questions without proper DDL / sample data (and to stop just copying clauses from the original without thinking). But I think an inner join is okay inside the apply anyway. The outer part of the query won't stop returning rows.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be that it should be `ph.supplierid`, but now I think about it, it seems odd to not know what the supplier is, or that the supplier isn't in the supplier table; the more I think about it the more I suspect the user is misusing a `LEFT JOIN` and it should be an `INNER JOIN`. But you're right, with no sample data, impossible to know. *Something* in the implied definitions in the OP doesn't add up though. :/

Comment: @ThomA I made best guesses in [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/awp87-qC) but without source data and expected outcome for these edge cases, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested!):

```
SELECT drawingN, partsID, partsName, x.supplierName
FROM BOM
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 purchase_history.partsID, supplier_list.supplierName
    FROM purchase_history
    LEFT JOIN supplier_list ON purchase_history.supplierID = supplier_list.supplierID
    WHERE partsID = 'A1234' AND supplierID <> '2991' AND supplierID <> '2992'
    ORDER BY purchaseDate DESC
           ) x ON x.partsID = BOM.partsID
WHERE drawingN = 'I16253'
```

- The `x` before the ON is an alias which defines how to refer to the results of this sub-query.
- THEN ON-clause (`x.partsID = BOM.partsID`) tells how to glue the two results together,
- `x.supplierName` is used to get the supplierName from the subquery, which we named `x`.

NOTE: As was (already noted) in the comments, above is just a simple glue-ing (is that a proper English word?) two queries to one.

Give me some time to get a proper SQL statement...

Comment: Needs correlation (they're trying to avoid hard-coding `A1234` - this query will never return `B5678`).

Comment: With the columns not qualified, as well, you're going to get an ambiguous column error (which the OP will most certainly be getting with their attempt as well).